# JQuery How to extract value from href tag?

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery.

If I have the following tag. What is the best JQuery method
to extract the value for "page" from the href.

```
<a href="Search/Advanced?page=2">2</a>
```

Malcolm

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is a one-liner regex:

```
var pageNum = $("#specificLink").attr("href").match(/page=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Note that this won't be perfect and will return false positives on things like `thepage=123`. Unless we can be sure that the URL always follows this exact structure, a full query parse might be more appropriate.

Comment: We could also consider checking for `[?&]`at the start, as well.

Comment: Just curious, what is the significance of the `[1]` at the end?

Comment: @escist: match returns an array, the [1] element will be the part within the () group i.e. the digits. [0] will be the whole thing `page=2`.

Comment: This is such a nice simple method. Very good when you dont need a full parse.

Answer (score 17):

I see two options here

```
var link = $('a').attr('href');
var equalPosition = link.indexOf('='); //Get the position of '='
var number = link.substring(equalPosition + 1); //Split the string and get the number.
```

I dont know if you're gonna use it for paging and have the text in the `<a>`-tag as you have it, but if you should you can also do

```
var number = $('a').text();
```

Comment: Your first solution will not work if there are other arguments in the link: Search/Advanced?search=mysearch&page=2 Another issue is that it only works with single character pages. It will not work with page 12 for example

Comment: Yes, I know about the other arguments, maybe should included that in the answer. But why wouldn't it work with multiple characters?

Comment: The answer does work for multiple characters. In fact I just tested this in Firebug. The single argument to substring is the starting location of the substring, if a second argument is not specified it will just read to the end of the string.

Nadia does bring up a good point about multiple arguments, though.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to extract the path with something like this:

```
$("a#myLink").attr("href");
```

Then take a look at this plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

It will help you handle all kinds of querystring things you want to do.

/Peter F

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that works by transforming the querystring into JSON...

```
var link = $('a').attr('href');

if (link.indexOf("?") != -1) {
    var query = link.split("?")[1];

    eval("query = {" + query.replace(/&/ig, "\",").replace(/=/ig, ":\"") + "\"};");

    if (query.page)
        alert(unescape(query.page));
    else
        alert('No page parameter');

} else {
    alert('No querystring');
}
```

I'd go with a library like the others suggest though... =)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not using any sample with `eval()` as it can introduce XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery [extension](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) by James Padoley

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($('a').on('Clicked').text().search('1') == -1)
{
    //Page == 1
}
else
{
    //Page != 1
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. What if the page number is 2?