# How to get value of href in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab the value of my href in jquery how is it done'?

This is what I have done:

```
$('#playbackbutton').click(
      function() {
         $("#playbackdiv").load("$('a:href').val();", [], function(){
               $("#playbackdiv").dialog("open");
            }
         );
         return false;
      }
```

I need to get the value of the href in my a tag.

here is the html:

```
<a href="/record/123.wav">play</a>
```

Comment: similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872217/jquery-how-to-extract-value-from-href-tag witch present a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a id="link" href="here.html">here</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    alert($('#link').attr('href'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a").attr("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the attr method