# Jquery extract id from url

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, match

I have this code:

```
var guestid = $(this).attr('href');
```

This gets me the current url, at the end of the url it has ?lid=8

How can I extract the 8 from that url? I tried this:

```
var guestid = $(this).attr('href').match(/\?lid=([0-9]+)$/);
```

But it returns null.

Comment: Similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872217/jquery-how-to-extract-value-from-href-tag

Comment: @Heikki Thank you! That gave me what I needed, var guestid = $(this).attr("href").match(/lid=([0-9]+)/)[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$(location).attr('href');` to get url using jquery or use `window.location.pathname;`. Your regular expression is correct

**EDIT**

```
var mRegexp = /\?lid=([0-9]+)$/; 
var match = mRegexp.exec($(this).attr('href'));
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: The code is used from a click action. When I do an alert on var guestid = $(this).attr('href'); it gives me back the url just fine. I just need to know how to extract the id from the url string guestid contains.

Comment: If I do this, var guestid = $(this).attr('href').match(/\?lid=[0-9]+$/); not surrounding the number with () then it gives me ?lid=8 as the value. So what am I doing wrong to just extra the number?

Comment: use `regex.exec`. `var mRegexp = /\?lid=([0-9]+)$/;
var match = mRegexp.exec(myString);lert(match[1]); `

Answer (score 1):

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// вызов: передаём параметр, который хотим достать из url'а
//(translation) Call: passing a parameter that we want to get out of
$.urlParam('Id');
```

[source](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/url-parameters-jquery/#.UCqBwp3N9-1)

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only thing in the querystring, do this:

```
var guestid = this.search.split('=')[1];
```

...and you've got it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zzhPj/

No need for a regex.