# Get anchor value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get get the **value** after # in the link when that link is clicked?

```
$(".myLink").click(function(){ 
    ???
}

<a href="myPage.php?a=asdasdasd#value" class="myLink">link</a>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872217/jquery-how-to-extract-value-from-href-tag

Comment: I think this is slightly different and I can probably get $_GET['page']...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('a.myLink').click(function() {
  alert(this.hash);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 for the `return false;` Without it the page navigates away so who cares about the javascript..

Comment: This answer needs the `split('#')` from @ezmilhouse's

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".myLink").click(function(evt){ 
    var arr = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    alert(arr[1]);
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In browsers supporting HTML5 you can use `this.hash` and then take `.substring(1)` to remove the hash itself from that string.

[This page](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTMLAnchorElement.html#HTMLAnchorElement.hash) suggests that support is pretty widespread anyway, even though its formal specification is pretty recent.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myLink").click(function(){ 
    var link=$(".myLink").attr('href');
    pos=link.indexOf("#", 0);
    value=link.substring(pos,link.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = $(this).attr("href");
var hash = href.indexOf("#") > 0 
    ? href.substring(href.indexOf("#") + 1) 
    : "";
```