# Getting the value of a link from HTML text

Tags: c#, regex

I have some long HTML text, something like this:

```
/*stuff*/
<a href="some/link.html">Link</a>
/*stuff*/
```

How can I crop this so that I get only the `some/link.html` text?

Comment: Using a regular expression [might not be the best strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/464709) here. Maybe you could use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ( I alway dream of citating this one , my preferred is 'Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions' ). Strange enough, one of the example on MSDN about Regex that I remember is about extracting links...

Answer (score 2):

Consider to have a look at the [Html Agility Pack.](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"(?<=<a\s+href="").*?(?="">)");
```

should do the trick.

Note that I am using the pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` with:
prefix = `<a\s+href="`
find = `.*?`
suffix = `">`

Answer (score -1):

using jquery you can do the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872217/jquery-how-to-extract-value-from-href-tag):

```
var pageNum = $("a#specificLink").attr("href").match(/page=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

and in .net c# [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html) might guide you in the right direction.

Comment: You ar epointing in the wrong direction: the tutorial you propose will match a link contained in comments, that is wrong.

Comment: This is not a jquery but C# question

Comment: @parapurarajkumar it doesn't mean he can't use jquery to achieve the same, I've posted questions in c# but accepted any solution as long as the end result works.  And Match m2 = Regex.Match(value, @"href=\""(.*?)\""" that line in that tutorial wouldn't work??  It's a matter of reading not assuming.