# jQuery: extract a part from a link Tag

Tags: jquery

How can I extract (with jQuery) the numbers from this a href Tags?

```
<a href="#slide1"></a>
<a href="#slide2"></a>
<a href="#slide3"></a>
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you able to get the href? Do you struggle with removing the "#slide" string? Conversion to a number?

Comment: I googled the first line of your question and found the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872217/jquery-how-to-extract-value-from-href-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  alert($(this).prop('href').replace(/[^\d]+/, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').each(function(){
   alert($(this).prop("href").replace("#slide",""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a').each(function() {
  alert($(this).prop('href').replace(/[^\d]+/, ''));
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jjXph/1/)**